# Scroll to a specific page using setContentOffset

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiscrollview

I am creating a family tree app for iPad pro 12.9. Here is my layout as seen in the storyboard.

[Family Tree Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK7Lk.png)

I have created a tall view controller to hold the 3 layers of the family, with a scrollview with 3 container views linking to more view controllers and scroll views to show information about the grandparents, parents, and kids.

I am having issues scrolling programatically to the right section when the user taps a button from the family tree to the information. 
I want the actions to go 
Tap on the person button -> segue to the tall view controller -> scroll to the right level of the scrollview for the vertical scroll -> scroll to the right level in grandparent/parent/kid scroll view.

I have classes set up for each of the scroll views, and classes for the view controllers.

In TreeViewController.swift I have

```
    @IBAction func sarah(_ sender: Any) {

    VerticalScrollView.contentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1024), animated:false)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPeople", sender: self)     
}
```

which is a button to move the vertical view controller down, then perform the segue.

I Think this the class rather than the instance of the class? How do I access the instance? Am I going about this the right way? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need pass in some way the information needed by the other viewController to scroll properly in viewWillAppear func of your destinationViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need define a property on your `destinationViewController` something like this

```
var scrollTo : CGPoint?
```

Then you must implement in your `prepareForSegue` method of your `TreeViewController` something like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPeople"{
        if let fullTreeViewController = segue.destination as? FullTreeViewController{
            if(sender is btnSarah)
             {
                fullTreeViewController.scrollTo = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1024)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your `destinationViewController`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         if(self.scrollTo != nil){
            self.verticalScrollView.contentOffset(self.scrollTo, animated:false)
         }

    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi This hasn't really worked for me, Im getting the error 'Instance member contentoffset cannot be used on type verticalscrillview' in the TreeViewController and in the destination controller: 'value of the type vertviewcontroller has no member verticalscrollview'

Comment: Can you post your class structure?, I only post an example, but i can help you if you post your class structure

Comment: I have set up individual classes for each of the view controllers and the scroll views 
http://imgur.com/a/Ks8Nb 
but all just inherit the base class of either a scroll view or view controller. e.g. VerticalScrollView.swift is 
'import UIKit

class VerticalScrollView: UIScrollView {
}
'